# ID generation strategy supported by Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, generator

Which ID generation strategies are supported by Oracle 12c?

**And which ID generation strategy is the best to use / with best performance?**

I was reading post about ID generation: http://sadalage.com/blog/2017/06/12/id-generation/

and wanted to check if is true that IDENTITY Id generation strategy has truly drawbacks in terms of round trips to DB as described or optimizer can prevent this?

Comment: "GENERATED AS IDENTITY" is done directly on the database when a record is inserted, so it involves no database roundtrips.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overhead *in the database* caused by identity columns.  I think some of the claims in the article are flawed.  The statement:

"Identity ID generation does not support preallocation, so requires a select after each insert"

might be true **for the ORM**, but is certainly not true of the database.  Most databases support the RETURNING clause, so the generated value from an identity column is trivially retrieved as part of the insert, ie:

```
insert into MY_TABLE
values ( ... )
returning ID_COLUMN into :my_host_variable
```

so it sounds more like they are opting for an ORM that does not do an adequate job.

Similarly, the statement

"In Oracle12c dropping of tables does not drop the sequence associated with the identity column leaving stale sequences in the database"

is trivially demonstrated to be false:

```
SQL> create table t ( x int generated as identity );

Table created.

SQL> select sequence_name from user_sequences;

SEQUENCE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------
ISEQ$$_159461

SQL> drop table t purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> select sequence_name from user_sequences;

no rows selected.
```

which also serves to demonstrate that IDENTITY columns (in Oracle) are implemented as sequences anyway.  So

"If the database provides features to use sequences they should be used. In databases that do not provide sequences identity columns have to be used"

is a questionable claim.

Comment: Thanks for this info.. Do you think that strategy with Identity ID generation is one of the best ones considering performance and not much drawbacks or would you suggest some other strategy for ID generation?

Comment: I can only comment on Oracle, but sequences or identity columns will be pretty much equivalent.   A good implementation will provide either with a single call using RETURNING as described above.  A poor implementation will be two trips no matter which method you use, either:

1 trip to get sequence number
1 trip to do the insert

or

1 trip to do the insert
1 trip to re-read the row to get the generated ID

Either obviously are not as good as one trip.